# After new ssd install windows crashes

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I've just installed a new crucial ssd and now occasionally windows will crash, I.e. I will get an error message saying windows has stopped working with options to end process.

All other windows continue to work fine games etc however networking also seems to stop.

I'm on windows 10 if that helps.

Comment: post more details (which SSD, which error message/error code)

Comment: Is the SSD the OS disk and how did the OS get on the SSD (installation, cloning, etc.)

Comment: Cloning using acronis, the crashes appear to occur when the film and video app is opened as well as occasionally with skype

Comment: So perhaps it is related to video rendering?